# C# String sorting... how to compare non-Ordinal but put lowercase after uppercase for strings starting with same letter?

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting, alphabetical-sort

Suppose I have four strings abc, Abc, Bca, and bca. The requirement is that these would be sorted (when alphabetical) to Abc, abc, Bca, bca.

With this code:

```
names.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a, b));
```

It is sorted as abc, Abc, bca, Bca. If I add StringComparison.Ordinal parameter then it is sorted as Abc, Bca, abc, bca. Is there any parameter I can pass to make it return Abc, abc, Bca, bca without having to sort it an additional time?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try any of the case *sensitive* options?

Comment: Meaning StringComparison.(anything not containing IgnoreCase)? Yes. Using of of the ignorecase ones just made it inconsistent--like you might get abc, Abc, Bca, bca or something.

Comment: And apart from Ordinal, they worked - As are sorted before Bs consistently, and the case is taken into account. It seems you want capitals to be sorted before small letters. Capitals appear after small letters because that's the order specified in `InvariantCulture` (essentially US) and your local culture. If you had a culture with different rules, capitals would come before small letters.

Comment: That is exactly the question I asked, what do you mean?

Comment: Hmmm... yeah, I might just get back to UX and point out that what they're asking is contrary to the current culture which seems like not what we should do.

Comment: What you asked is “Is there any parameter”, so if you've tried them all and all of them aren't suitable, the answer is no.

Comment: You could make a custom Compare function that first compares using `OrdinalIgnoreCase`, and then if the result is 0, compare the first letter of each using `Ordinal` and return that as the result. It would be a bit weird if there were capital letters in the middle of a string though, since that would still be sorted case insensitively. I think not doing this is probably the better solution, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom comparer that first sorts case-insensitively, then only if the strings are the same it sorts case-sensitive..

```cs
names.Sort((a, b) => {
    var compare = string.Compare(a, b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (compare != 0)
        return compare;
    compare = string.Compare(a, b, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    return compare;
});
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w0VN18)